# Excel Macro VBA - Insert a Cell instead of Copying

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried to search through multiple questions related to my problem and trying to change my own code to fit the solutions, however im not very good at programming and thus none of the solutions has helped me.

Therefore here is my problem: I have created a code that by a button push copies a entire row to another sheet, if it contains a specific value.

However because there is a total Sum of the values at the bottom, the code automatically copies them beneath the sum rendering it useless. If I change the range to copy the cells before the total sum, the next problem arises, that the rows are copied and not inserted. Thus at some time the total sum will be overwritten by copied cells.

I don't want a work around to put the sum at the top, I wish that the cells are simply inserted above the total sum, rather than copied:

```
Sub Test()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G" & "999")
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each xCell In xRg
    If CStr(xCell.Value) = "Test" Then
        xCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xCell.EntireRow.Delete
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I think I have managed to narrow it down to the following line which is the problem:

```
xCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
```

Somehow I need to change it so it inserts a row, between the total sum and the previous/last inserted row. Thus so code "J + 1" needs to be changed to the distance between the Total Sum and the last inserted row in my case around "J - 5". However, this still does not solve my "Copy / Insert" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
xCell.EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: It should be `Range("A" & J)` instead of `Range("A" & J + 1)` this was the next free row and you need to select the last used row to insert **before** it.

Comment: Yeah that may be tweaked as per the requirement. The idea here was to show that how can a copied row be inserted.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. as said I changed "J - 6" and thus this inserted the cell above the total sum

Comment: @KarstenBraasch As an improvement I would give the entire row of the total sum [a name](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) and then you can use `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("MySumRowName").Insert shift:=xlDown`. This way you don't need to change the macro if the number of rows (J-6) changes.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad your issue is resolved. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a row before you copy the values:

```
'Inserting a Row at at Row 2
Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
```